# How to connect to bluetooth with a web app to play audios?

Tags: javascript, bluetooth

I'm new to bluetooth connection for JavaScript. I want to make my web app connect to a physical button for playing audios, which is connecting to bluetooth with a board. But my web app doesn't connect to the board.

I don't have a board with me now so I try to connect with my iPhone first, so I still cannot connect it.. What else do I miss?

Even if I can connect, how do I press the physical button once and play a audio, and then press it again, it will play the next audio?

My html:

```
<button id="bluetooth" stlye=display:none> Connect to bluetooth</button>
```

My JavaScript:

```
  $("#bluetooth").on("click", function(){

        console.log('Searching Bluetooth Device...');

        navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
            acceptAllDevices: true,
            optionalServices: ['battery_service']
        })

        .then(device => { 
            console.log('aa: '+ device.gatt.connect())
            console.log('Name: ' + device.name);
            console.log('id ' + device.id);
            console.log('Connected: ' + device.gatt.connected);

            // Attempts to connect to remote GATT Server.
            return device.gatt.connect();
        })

        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Something went wrong. " + error);
        });
   });
```

This is from the console:

```
index.html:166 Searching Bluetooth Device...
index.html:177 aa: [object Promise]
index.html:178 Name: IPhone of Johnny
index.html:179 id HoC4uQMnDGuMRTWhj0HxKw==
index.html:180 Connected: false
```

Comment: why are you trying to connect twice to it?

Comment: I’m sorry. What do you mean?

Comment: You mean  console.log('aa: '+ device.gatt.connect()) and console.log('Connected: ' + device.gatt.connected); ? The first time I was trying to do only console.log('Connected: ' + device.gatt.connected); But I still got false, so I was trying to output gatt.connect()